# Which Statement is True and Which One is False?

Tags: real-analysis

Which of the following statements is true or false and why?

[Image Provided](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxSDx.jpg)

Comment: $(a)$ is false, consider suitable $y$ such that discriminant is negative. Then for $(b)$, this is related to $(a)$ by considering negation

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you, say, sketch the  function of $x$ in question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is wrong, since the global minimum of $x^2 - 2x -3$ is -4. The second one is right, just pick $y = -5$ (whatever number smaller than -4).